# Laravel ordering and limit results of a left join

Tags: laravel, query-builder

One to many relationships, each product has many prices

table `products`

id | name | slug | created_at | update_at

table `prices`

id | product_id | title | price | link

I want to get the data limit of product limit 20 table and order created_at and each product get the lowest price, order column price. I want to use the query builder.
i tried

```
$products = DB::table('products')
        ->leftJoin('prices', 'products.id', '=', 'prices.product_id')
        ->select('products.id', 'products.name')->distinct()
        ->selectRaw('max(prices.price) as price')
        ->groupby('products.id')
        ->orderby('products.updated_at')
        ->get();
```

but it get all products and table `prices` order column id

Comment: why you are not using eloquent?

Comment: @AbirAdak because of the large number of tables and query builder performance better than eloquent

Answer (score 0):

You can use Eloquent Like This

```
public function price() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\model\Prices' , 'product_id' ,'id');
    }
```

and get like this , It will give you the mapped price only for your specific product

```
$product = Product::with('price')
                  ->where(do the stuffs)
                  ->orderBy(do the stuffs) 
                  ->get();
```

Or you can use the callback as well in with()

Comment: i tried $products = Product::with(['price' => function ($price) {
            $price->orderBy('price', 'desc');
            $price->take(20);
        }])->take(20)->get(); each product hasmany prices. but that eloquent 20 product get only 1 price lowest. I want each product get 1 price lowest